# How to design a serializable class such that any non-serialized attribute leads to a compile-time error?

Tags: c++, serialization, type-safety

Say you have the following code:

```
class A {
  bool _attribute1;
};

// Arbitrarily using std::string, not the point of this question
std::string serialize(const A&);
```

Now a developer adds a new `bool _attribute2` to `class A` and forgets to update the `serialize` function, which leads to a bug at runtime. (Already been there ?)

Is there a way to turn this issue into compile-time error ? As C++ doesn't support reflection, I have the feeling this is impossible, but I may be missing something.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: The only thing I could think of would be a static assert somewhere on sizeof(A). Hence, if something gets added, something will fail to compile, until the new class member is serialized and the static assert adjusted accordingly.

Comment: You could add a custom script or program to your makefile or IDE pre-build steps to check that all members of the class are included in the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using c++1z you could make use of structured binding:

```
struct S {
    bool b;
    //bool c; // causes error
};

int main() {
    S s;
    auto [x] = s;
    (void)x;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ENSK2TP6OHYCj3W5)

Comment: Nice. Would you recommend that the serialization function then use `x`?

Comment: @Muscampester As long as you plan to serialize only public fields of the class it is relatively easy to perform

Comment: I see this would also work with `auto&`. What could be done about private members?

Comment: @Muscampester Unfortunately I don't think it can be extended to private/protected members

Comment: I'll try to remember that when most industrial projects are migrated to C++17 fifty years from now :) .

Comment: Could this example be rewritten in C++11 using a [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)?

Comment: @Muscampester no can do. `std::tie` allows only to assign to its result instance of `std::tuple`

Answer (score 2):

The following one should work with C++11.
A bit tricky indeed, it's based on a comment of [@SamVarshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332602/how-to-design-a-serializable-class-such-that-any-non-serialized-attribute-leads#comment69867978_41332602):

```
#include<cstddef>
#include<functional>

template<std::size_t> struct Int { int i; };
template<std::size_t> struct Char { char c; };
template<std::size_t> struct Bool { bool c; };

template<typename, template<std::size_t> class...>
struct Base;

template<template<std::size_t> class... T, std::size_t... I>
struct Base<std::index_sequence<I...>, T...>: T<I>... {};

template<template<std::size_t> class... T>
struct Check final: Base<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>, T...> {};

class A final {
    bool _attribute1;
    bool _attribute2;
private:
    char _attribute3;
    // int _attribute4;
};

void serialize(const A &) {
    static_assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(Check<Bool, Bool, Char>), "!");
    // do whatever you want here...
}

int main() {
    serialize(A{});
}
```

The basic idea is to list all the types of the data members and define a new type from them with a mixin. Then it's a matter of putting a `static_assert` in the right place.
Note that private data members are taken in consideration too.

There exist some corner cases that could break it, but maybe it can work for your real code.

---

As a side note, it can be further simplified if C++14 is an option:

```
#include<cstddef>

template<typename... T>
constexpr std::size_t size() {
    std::size_t s = 0;
    std::size_t _[] = { s += sizeof(T)... };
    (void)_;
    return s;
}

class A final {
    bool _attribute1;
    bool _attribute2;
private:
    char _attribute3;
    // int _attribute4;
};

void serialize(const A &) {
    static_assert(sizeof(A) == size<bool, bool, char>(), "!");
    // ...
}

int main() {
    serialize(A{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doomed to use c++11 and still you are interested in serializing only the public fields you could create trait testing if the type can be constructed using list initialization with a given parameters types but not even one more (of any type):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct default_param {
    template <class T>
    operator T();
};

template <class T, class...>
using typer = T;

template <class, class, class... Args>
struct cannot_one_more: std::true_type {};

template <class Tested, class... Args>
struct cannot_one_more<typer<void, decltype(Tested{std::declval<Args>()..., default_param{}})>, Tested, Args...>: std::false_type {
};

template <class...>
struct is_list_constructable: std::false_type {};

template <class Tested, class... Args>
struct is_list_constructable<Tested(Args...)>: is_list_constructable<void, Tested, Args...> { };

template <class Tested, class... Args>
struct is_list_constructable<typer<void, decltype(Tested{std::declval<Args>()...}), typename std::enable_if<cannot_one_more<void, Tested, Args...>::value>::type>, Tested, Args...>: std::true_type { };

struct S {
    bool b;
    //bool c; // causes error
};

int main() {
    static_assert(is_list_constructable<S(bool)>::value, "!");
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cvIfVcAcB7EyYrH6)